# need assistance inserting data from core data into a table view

Tags: ios, swift, xcode

I created an entity named Friends which holds data about a friend.
I have one view controller which allows the user to add a friend which works correctly ( I can print results in a text view)
and now I am having difficulties trying to display the data in a table view.

the following two functions are to set and get a friend in appDelegate

**AppDelegate.swift**

```
func storeFriendInfo (studentID: Int, firstName: String, lastName: String,gender: String, courseStudy: String, age: Int, address: String){
        let context = getContext()
        let entity = NSEntityDescription.entity(forEntityName: "Friends", in: context)
        let transc = NSManagedObject(entity: entity!, insertInto: context)
        transc.setValue(studentID, forKey: "studentID")
        transc.setValue(firstName, forKey: "firstName")
        transc.setValue(lastName, forKey: "lastName")
        transc.setValue(gender, forKey: "gender")
        transc.setValue(courseStudy, forKey: "courseStudy")
        transc.setValue(age, forKey: "age")
        transc.setValue(address, forKey: "address")
        
        do {
            try context.save()
        }catch let error as NSError{
            print("Could not save \(error), \(error.userInfo)")
        } catch {
    }

}
    func getFriendInfo () -> String {
        var info = ""
        let fetchRequest = NSFetchRequest<NSManagedObject>(entityName: "Friends")
        do {
            let searchResults = try getContext().fetch(fetchRequest)
            for trans in searchResults as [NSManagedObject]{
                let ID_ = String(trans.value(forKey: "studentID") as! Int )
                let firstName_ = (trans.value(forKey: "firstName") as! String )
                let lastName_ = (trans.value(forKey: "lastName") as! String )
                let gender_ = (trans.value(forKey: "gender") as! String )
                let courseStudy_ = (trans.value(forKey: "courseStudy") as! String )
                let address_ = (trans.value(forKey: "address") as! String )
                let age_ = String(trans.value(forKey: "age") as! Int )
                info = info + ID_ + ", " + firstName_ + ", " + lastName_ + ", " + gender_ + ", " + courseStudy_ + ", " + age_ + ", " + address_ + "\n"
                
            }
        } catch {
            print("Error with request: \(error)")
        }
        return info 
    }

}
```

the function below is how I add a friend

**addFriendClass.swift**

```
  @IBAction func saveFriend(_ sender: Any) {
        let appDelegate = UIApplication.shared.delegate as! AppDelegate
        appDelegate.storeFriendInfo(studentID: Int(studentID.text!)!, firstName: firstName.text!, lastName: lastName.text!, gender: gender_text.text!, courseStudy: study_text.text!, age: Int(age.text!)!, address: address.text!)
    }
    
    
}
```

and this is how I am trying to display the data

**ViewFriendClass.swift**

```
import UIKit

class view_19342665: UIViewController,UITableViewDelegate, UITableViewDataSource {
    
    @IBOutlet weak var tableView: UITableView!
    
    var Friends: [String] = []
    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
        return Friends.count
    }
    
    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
        let cell:UITableViewCell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "friends", for: <#T##IndexPath#>)
        cell.textLabel?.text = Friends[indexPath.row]
        return cell
    }
    

    
    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        // Do any additional setup after loading the view.
        let appDelegate = UIApplication.shared.delegate as! AppDelegate
        //text.text = appDelegate.getFriendInfo()
    }
    
}
```

I followed a tutorial online but Im unsure how to store the results from core data into my array.

This is my expected output for the display

---

### 193111, james, bond, 34, Male, Sydney, Comp Sci

---

### 143223, Sam, bond, 11, Female, Sydney, Comp Sci

this is what I am aiming for:

every time a user submits a new friend it gets stored in the core data as an array and that way when i fetch the results i can use that array to display it into the table?

Comment: You could implement a fetchedResultsController in your TableView to auto refresh it on CoreData changes (e.g. saving a new Friend). https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=ZRwXbb1cOFw

Comment: Oh right but I'm having troubles displaying the data in the table to begin with. It's my first time usiusinusiusing swift and what I'd like to do is store the friend in a array and then loop through the array and each element is a row in the table

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you create an entity Friends in core data you also get a class named Friends that you can use in your code and you should definitely use that instead of the horrible string handling you have now in your fetch request.

(it's better to name the entity in singular form, so Friend instead of Friends, since each instance represent one friend)

Here is how I would write getFriendInfo

```
func getFriendInfo() -> [Friends] {
    let fetchRequest: FetchRequest<Friends> = Friends.fetchRequest()

    do {
        return try getContext().fetch(fetchRequest)                
        }
    } catch {
        print("Error with request: \(error)")
        return []
    }
}
```

then change the class property Friends to

```
var friends: [Friends] = []
```

and use Friends objects when creating the table view content instead. If you don't want to work with multiple columns a simplified solution for now could be to have a computed property to display in the table view cell

```
extension Friends {
    var displayInfo: String {
         "\(studentID), \(firstName), \(lastName), \(gender), \(courseStudy), \(age), \(address)"
    }
}
```

and use it when writing to the cell

```
cell.textLabel?.text = friends[indexPath.row].displayInfo
```

You can of course also use the `Friends` class when saving a new object but I leave that for you to figure out if you want to.

Comment: thank you i got it to worked
one thing you know in the extension class how can i we write that string to print a new line after every second variable so display is 

12345
james bond
 .... 
 .... 
right now its all on the same line and cant fit

Comment: @william_ Please do not edit your question like this, now my answer is pointless since it is already in the question!

Comment: @william_ To make the line fit you can just add \n where you see fit in the displayInfo variable .

Comment: oh sorry didnt think of that
yikes now i need to resize the cell height to fit it all... hopefully google can help with that
but thankyou for your answer

Comment: @william_ Or maybe you don't need to display _all_ the info?